# inserting html table values in mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to submit a `html` table values into `mysql` table. First two columns of `html` table are fetched from `mysql` table `'student'` and third column is to be filled online. I want to insert all three columns to another table in `msyql`. I am just facing problem in inserting all table values. code is as under:-

```
<html>

<body>


<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');

if (!$connection){
    echo 'Not connected to server';
}

$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db');

if (!$select_db){
    echo 'Not connected to database';
}
$SelectClass = $_POST ['selectclass'];


$sql= "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class = '$SelectClass'";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
 <body>
    <div class="container">

    <h1><strong>Please enter marks of each student for subject</strong></h1>
    <table id = "result" class="data-table">
        <caption class="title"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Marks Obtained</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'."<div class='search-block clearfix'><input name='obtmarks' placeholder='' type='number'></div>".'</td>

                </tr>';
            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;


        }?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="insert" align="right">Update<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add hidden fields to your form with the values of `$row['student_id']` and `$row['student_name']` so you get those values when you submit the form.

Comment: i am totally blank of it at this time.. can you please share exact coding

Comment: i am stuck how to insert first two columns of html table into marks table, because these are fetched from other table through loop.

Comment: You could give the td elements name attributes and use the `^=` selector and loop through all of the values and build an array from that. You then lopp through that array in php and perform your insert for the specific indexes. Might be a more advanced approach, but an approach nonetheless.

Comment: @Martin student_id and student_name fetched through loop above and i am getting obtained marks in third column from input box. There are 20 students whom marks will be submitted. I know i have to implement a loop to insert all three columns, but dont know how to insert fetched values. can you share some code please

Comment: @Akhtar does `<input name='obtmarks' placeholder='' type='number'>` hold any value? Personally I don't really make use of the old-fashioned `<form>` tags anymore, but if your input field(s) hold actual values, then they should be posted. Try to var_dump your post values and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the updated code below :

```
<body>


<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');

if (!$connection){
    echo 'Not connected to server';
}

$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db');

if (!$select_db){
    echo 'Not connected to database';
}
$SelectClass = $_POST ['selectclass'];


$sql= "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class = '$SelectClass'";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
mysqli_close($connection);

//***********Form Submit Goes Here***********//
if($_POST)
{
    $student_id     =   $_POST['student_id'];
    $student_name   =   $_POST['student_name'];
    $student_marks  =   $_POST['obtmarks'];

    //your code for insertion....

}
?>
 <body>
    <div class="container">

    <h1><strong>Please enter marks of each student for subject</strong></h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table id = "result" class="data-table">
        <caption class="title"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Marks Obtained</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value='.$row['student_id'].'>
                    <td>'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_name" value='.$row['student_name'].'>
                    <td>'."<div class='search-block clearfix'><input name='obtmarks' placeholder='' type='number'></div>".'</td>

                </tr>';
            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;


        }?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="insert" align="right">Update<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me.. but its only adding last row of table i have 20 rows at this time. Can you please do it with loop?